# Trying to intall Semi Automatic Plugin in QGis but it shows error

Tags: qgis-plugins

Semi-Automatic Classification Plugin : HTTPSConnectionPool(host='github.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /semiautomaticgit/remotior_sensus/archive/refs/heads/master.zip (Caused by NewConnectionError(': Failed to establish a new connection: [WinError 10060] A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond'))

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE. Only providing the error message is not enough to explain your problem. Please add some context, the version of QGIS, how did you try to install it, your operating system configuration etc.

Comment: Sure I will update it